# upload to app store but not public

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

i am currently looking for a deploying solution for an iPhone app.

is it possible to upload an app to the app store so it won't be shown
in the search but only with a direct link to the app?
i am trying to create a private beta with more than 100 people so i
can't use testflight solution

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that due to Apple restrictions. When an app is in the appstore, it is public.

The only (legal way that I know of) to do what you want is to become a member of the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) - or use a solution such as Testflight, and live with the 100 device limit. The Enterprise Program lets you distribute apps across an organization without restrictions.